# Find value and copy entire row to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste, vlookup

I'm trying to create a vba code but I'm not succeeding.

I want to search on COLUMN "F", for value: "Answered" 
then copy row from "COLUM B TO F" and paste on sheet "ControlAnswered" lastrow;

Comment: What have you already tried? [See this article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
Sub SpecialCopy()
    Dim targetSh As Worksheet
    Set targetSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ControlAnswered")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 6).Value = "Answered" Then
            Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).Copy Destination:=targetSh.Range("A" & targetSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I should say that you will not always going to find people that will write code for you